# Invalid parameter for estimator Pipeline

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, grid-search

I'm getting value error with the following code and can't find why.

I can use any params!

```
df_final = df.copy()

X, y = df_final.drop("Churn", axis=1), df_final.Churn

lr_pipeline = make_pipeline(preprocessor, under_sampling, LogisticRegression())
dt_pipeline = make_pipeline(preprocessor, under_sampling, DecisionTreeClassifier())
rf_pipeline = make_pipeline(preprocessor, under_sampling, RandomForestClassifier())
gb_pipeline = make_pipeline(preprocessor, under_sampling, XGBClassifier())

estimators = [
    ("lr", lr_pipeline),
    ("dt", dt_pipeline),
    ("rf", rf_pipeline),
    ("gb", gb_pipeline)
]

classifiers = StackingClassifier(estimators=estimators, final_estimator=RandomForestClassifier())

params = {
    'final_estimator__n_estimators': [10, 100, 1000],
    'rf__max_depth': [5, 10, 15],
    'rf__min_samples_split': [2, 5, 10],
    'lr__C': [0.1, 1, 10],
}

cv = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

models = GridSearchCV(estimator=classifiers, param_grid=params, cv=cv, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=-1)

models.fit(X, y)

print(f"Melhores parâmetros: {models.best_params_}")
print(f"Acurácia: {models.best_score_:.4f}")
```

The error:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter C for estimator Pipeline(steps=[('columntransformer',
                 ColumnTransformer(remainder='passthrough',
                                   transformers=[('minmaxscaler',
                                                  MinMaxScaler(),
                                                  <sklearn.compose._column_transformer.make_column_selector object at 0x7f1dec598c10>),
                                                 ('onehotencoder',
                                                  OneHotEncoder(),
                                                  <sklearn.compose._column_transformer.make_column_selector object at 0x7f1dec598f40>),
                                                 ('functiontransformer',
                                                  FunctionTransformer(func=<function identity at 0x7f1dec58fc10>),
                                                  ['SeniorCitizen'])])),
                ('randomundersampler',
                 RandomUnderSampler(random_state=42,
                                    sampling_strategy='not minority')),
                ('logisticregression', LogisticRegression())]). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

The result of `LogisticRegression().get_params().keys()`

The 'C' parameter is there!

```
dict_keys(['C', 'class_weight', 'dual', 'fit_intercept', 'intercept_scaling', 'l1_ratio', 'max_iter', 'multi_class', 'n_jobs', 'penalty', 'random_state', 'solver', 'tol', 'verbose', 'warm_start'])
```

I already check a lot of examples, all of them seems to be the same as my code above!

Heres an example:
https://michael-fuchs-python.netlify.app/2020/04/29/stacking-with-scikit-learn/

Answer (score 1):

The `make_pipeline` function creates an intermediate `Pipeline` level, which is not handled in your fit param addressing syntax.

Right now you have: `lr__C`. But you should be having `lr__logisticregression__C`.